# How to send 100,000 emails weekly and avoid being considered spammer

Tags: linux, email, spam, mailing-list

I have a mailing list with 100,000 email addresses, and I have to send it an email weekly.

What application/program/webapp/script/etc do I have to use to send 100,000 emails weekly and avoid being considered a spammer?

No program for only Windows or Mac please. I use Linux.

Comment: How to rob a bank and avoid being considered robber.

Comment: I'm sure that you wouldn't be considered a spammer if you sent them all to yourself...

Comment: Assuming the number of subscribers once started at 1, so this list has been around some time: how did you send the messages in the time the list grew to 100,000? And with what results?

Comment: @Arjan: "100 [100.000] emails is not that much, really" It is not uncommon for a dot to be used for [digit grouping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Digit_grouping).

Comment: @Dennis, I know, we use the dot when writing in Dutch too. But not in too many English dialects, right?

Answer (score 7):

First of all I'd read Jeff's article on configuring your mail infrastructure DNS bits:

[So You'd Like to Send Some Email (Through Code)](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html)

Next, you may need to consider signing up with a bulk mail service that many ISP's provide. Whether you're sending mail from your broadband connection or your hosting environment, most ISP's will limit the volume of mail you can send on a daily or hourly basis.

Comment: Great link, thanks. +1

Good question, thanks. +1

Comment: Wow you managed to answer this without sounding cynical! +1

Comment: @Ivo - I give everyone the benefit of the the doubt...too many people jump to conclusions. :)

Answer (score 4):

One email or a million, it really makes no difference what software you use. Quite simply, any software capable of sending a single message is capable of sending as many as you like. For the mailing lists I look after I use a simple Perl script.

The software you use is not even a factor in whether you're considered a spammer or not. Just some of the things that do matter are:

- A mailer that doesn't try to fake any message header,
- Proper DNS configuration (reverse pointer and SPF record).
- No virus/malware in the message, or anything that might even trigger a false positive. It only takes one to get you on a blocklist.
- Every message goes out to someone who has voluntarily signed up to the list.
- Use DKIP/Domainkey signing.
- Don't send by CCing to long lists of recipients. One to address per message.
- etc., etc.

Fail on any of those, especially the third, fourth and fifth points, you can pretty much expect to be listed as a spammer, with no sympathy from me.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, would recommend checking your Email system against this [Email Server Test](http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test)

Answer (score 0):

Another useful site to test settings is [MXToolbox](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/)